# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\stage\core\addUsers.php on line 20

Tags: php, pdo

I get this error  Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\stage\core\addtUsers.php on line 20

```
    if(!empty($_POST["add_record"])) {
  require_once("connection.php");

  $data = [
    'username'  =>$_POST["username"],
    'password'  =>$_POST["password"],
    'role'   =>$_POST["role"],
    'photo'    =>$_POST["photo"],
    'nom-prenom'   =>$_POST["nom-prenom"] 
  ];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username,password,role,photo,nom-prenom) VALUES (:username,:password,:role,:photo,:nom-prenom)";
  $statement = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
  $result = $statement->execute($data);
    if (!empty($result) ){
      header('location:users.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are any of the array elements empty?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: no there is no empty array elemnets

Comment: i use sha1 cryptage for password

Comment: Not in this code, you don't. SHA1 is not sufficient for passwords any longer.

Comment: this part of code is only  to add users

Comment: That is when you should hash passwords, when you add them. Add the colons to the array `':username' =>...` etc.

Comment: it's work with username ,password and role but when i add the photo and nom-prenom i have this problem

Comment: it's work with username ,password and role but when i add the photo and nom-prenom i have this problem

Comment: Post your markup for the form here. Edit our question to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `-` in the name of a placeholder. This will be understood as an arithmetic subtraction.

Consider this example:

```
$pdo->prepare('SELECT :num-1')->execute(['num'=>5]);
```

It looks for a param called `:num` or `num` and then it will subtract 1 from it.
A good IDE might even help you out by highlighting this: 
[image]
Although with letters it would highlight it the same color as a column name, which could also be missed.

Try to use a different placeholder name e.g. `:nom_prenom`